# Getting the first element in an array/any collection

Tags: arrays, collections

So the other day I had my colleague review my code and he saw that I was using array[0], in Java terms this is basically getting the first element of the array. I did this several times for different purposes, all of which is to get the first element in an array/collection, for example list.get(0), to which he strongly disagreed with.

His argument was that somebody from non-programming background would have problem understanding it and using 0 in such cases is basically hard-coding, which is bad practice. I google-ed several times and all suggestions to getting the first element in an array or any collection is providing them the index, which is 0 in this case.

Could anyone provide me with a suggestion on getting the first element in a meaningful way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using linkedlist's [getfirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getFirst%28%29) method to get the first element of the list.

If you were to use an ArrayList is backed by an array and hence its perfectly valid to use index as 0 to get first element.

Comment: Sorry that I did not make myself clear enough, I was actually looking for a good way of accessing the first element, not collection specific way like the getFirst you mentioned. Something like int first = 0 then array[first], but I'm not sure if there's any better way out there.

Comment: Am afraid there would be any better way.